# Wix installer: access multiple property values

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

If I create a property with multiple arguments like

```xml
<Property Id="MyProp" Value="Arg1=value1;Arg2=value2" />
```

How can I access a specific value in a CustomAction, e.g.

```xml
<CustomAction Id="MyCA" Property="MyProp" Value="[MyProp.Arg1]" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you wouldn't set the value to "Arg1=value1;Arg2=value2", you'd set the property to "value1;value2" and then tokenize the substrings around the ';' character. The custom action should know what to do with the arguments without needing to list argument names.